# ggplot2: about the size legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
ggplot(college, mapping = aes(x = tuition,
                              y = sat_avg,
                              size = undergrads,
                              color = control)) + 
geom_point(alpha = 1/2) + 
geom_smooth(se = FALSE)
```

Hi all, after typing the code above, I found the legend of the size (undergrads) seems strange. They are supposed to be round ones instead of the overlapping shape. Anyone knows what's going wrong? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! To help to be helped, add some data that can be used to make work your code, and read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

I used the `iris` dataset to test this as I don't know where `college` is from, but it should work.  You just need to add `show.legend = F`

```
ggplot(college, mapping = aes(x = tuition,
                              y = sat_avg,
                              size = undergrads,
                              color = control)) + 
geom_point(alpha = 1/2) + 
geom_smooth(se = FALSE, show.legend = F)
```

Comment: You are a genius! Just wondering why the default setting of the size legend is not round shapes...

Comment: Alternatively you could remove the size mapping from the main `ggplot()` call and put it inside `geom_point()`

Comment: That's the better solution.